# Apply Intellij Code Improvement Suggestions

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using [`Intellij`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) for `Java` development. In the code editor on the right, it displays some yellow markers which indicate issue with my code, e.g. improvement suggestions. When I hover over the affected code line it tell me what to do. Unfortunately I didn't find a way of automatically applying said suggestion. How do I do that? I don't want to do fixes by hand but rather allow `Intellij` to do them for convenience.

`CTRL + Space` is only code completion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place the cursor over the highlighted code, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, select the suggested fix and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

You can also apply the fix for all problems of the given type within specified scope (current file, project, ...). If you want to do that, just select *Run inspection on* from the menu that is shown.

I'm not sure if there is a way to apply these fixes automatically completely without user intervention, but even if there was, it probably wouldn't be very user friendly, as the warnings are sometimes false-positive.

Comment: Just to clarify, that's the key cursor, not the mouse cursor, so for a Mac user the steps would be 1. key cursor over code; 2. tickle code with mouse pointer; 3. fn + alt/option + enter

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a code suggestion it it simply <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while the cursor is over the highlighted code. I would strongly suggest not automatically applying suggestions and to use your better judgement.

I can personally attest that while it's a little extra work, being able to choose the suggestions validity is much better. There's been more than a few times when the suggestion wouldn't make sense in the context.

As a sidenote I'd suggest having a reference for the KB shortcuts open so you can improve your speed within the IDE: [Mac](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf) or [Windows/Linux](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)